# Заливка для рисовалки в python

Tags: python, pygame

Я делаю небольшую пиксельную рисовалку. И хотел бы сделать инструмент заливки. Есть ли алгоритм для того, чтобы от какой-либо точки проверить двумерный массив. Как изменить значения той части массива, которая имеет те же значения, что и выбранная точка, и которая на одной зоне с точкой?

Comment: Пригласите кода в студию.

Comment: вопрос, случайно, не про собственный велосипед вместо [существующего](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill)?